# How to make request to api on kong getway from browser

Tags: angular, kong, kong-plugin

I configured service/route on **KONG** without any host name and paths. I able to make GET request from browser(my web app) but whenever doing **POST, PUT, DELETE** call from browser(web app) getting **CORS(cross origin Resource Sharing)** issue. But I'm able to test from **postman**.

I enabled **CORS plugin** on route but no luck.
Here is my service and route configuration on Kong Admin.
[image]

Route configuration:
[image]

CORS Plugin configuration on route:
[image]

Comment: https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/cors/

Comment: @jitender I enabled CORS plugin on route but no luck. I already referred https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/cors/

Comment: did you finally solve this?

Comment: @DaviesTobialex no...I'm not able to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, you just have to add within the methods allowed in the route: OPTIONS